# No email attachments to Document library when using data driven subscriptions

Tags: document-library, reporting-services, reports, incoming-email, email-enabled-library

We have recently migrated to SharePoint 2013 and setup document libraries to publish reports to.

When we send an email with an attachment to the document library from a users mailbox, the document library acts as expected and detaches the email and publishes it to a subfolder inside the library. However when we schedule reports using data driven subscriptions and add the email address as a CC, the subfolder gets created but there is no attachment.

What could cause this issue?

Thanks for your time